# Solidity error: Unexpected token h in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, json, ethereum, solidity

Hey I'm developing a simple smart contract on solidity and I crashed into a problem. Everytime I try to run setWord function I get an error "transact to HelloWorldContract.setWord errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 2" What could be the problem?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract HelloWorldContract{
string word = "Hello World";
address issuer;
function HelloWorldContract(){
    issuer = msg.sender;    
}
function getWord() constant returns(string) {
    return word;
}
function setWord(string newWord) returns(string) {
    if(issuer != msg.sender){
        return "this is not the creator!";
    }
    else{
     word = newWord;
     return "this is the creator!";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be that you're using [Remix IDE](http://remix.ethereum.org).

Don't forget to add double quotes around the arguments you're passing:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass argument string in double quotes - "*helloWorld*" instead of just *helloWorld*.